# Extendscript how to get path of script when a .jsx file is double-clicked to run

Tags: filenames, adobe-indesign, extendscript

Simple code:

```
#target indesign
#targetengine indesign
alert($.fileName);
```

[Output when started from extendscript toolkit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bwl6.png)

[Output when a .jsx file is double-clicked to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlsPM.png)

How to get path to the script if script is double-clicked to run?

Comment: Which version of InDesign do you use? And where do you double-click the script? In the scripts panel?

Comment: Tried CS4, CS6 and CC. Double-click .jsx file in via windows explorer containg that simple code.

Comment: I think ID scripts are not really supposed to be executed via the Explorer. The reason is, ExtendScript then sends the scripts over Bridge Talk, which makes Bridge Talk the executing script and that's why you get that error. I would strongly recommend to execute your scripts via double click from the scripts panel instead.

Comment: Hi,

As far as I know - double clicking involves bridgeTalk, so your script is read and its contents is sent as a String into target application. So your script (a file) is not an active one - it is used only to read the content and left.

Jarek